# including the output of remote php script in webpage

Tags: php, jquery, html, widget

I have a php script that resides on a remote server. I am trying to include the output from that script in a webpage that has some jquery running, making a widget.

```
<?php
include('includes/include.php');
//date play
$today = date('Y-m-d');

//run query to find today's events
$query = "SELECT e.*, l.* FROM hc_events e
   LEFT JOIN hc_locations l ON (l.PkID = e.LocID)
   WHERE e.IsActive = 1 AND e.IsApproved = 1 AND e.StartDate >= '". $today ."' 
   ORDER BY e.SeriesID, e.SubmittedAt, e.StartDate, e.Title
   LIMIT 0, 5";

$result = doQuery($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

  //print_r($row);

  if($row['LocationName'] && $row['LocationAddress'] && $row['LocationCity'] && $row['LocationCity']){
    $locationInfo = $row['LocationName'] . ', ' . $row['LocationAddress'] . ' ' . $row['LocationAddress2'] . ' ' . ucwords($row['LocationCity']) . ', ' . $row['LocationZip'];
  }
  else{
    $locationInfo = $row['Name'] . ', ' . $row['Address'] . ' ' . $row['Address2'] . ' ' . ucwords($row['City']) . ', ' . $row['Zip'];
  }


  $contactInfo = $row['ContactName'] . ' -- ' . $row['ContactEmail'] . ', ' . $row['ContactPhone'];
  ?> 

  <fieldset class="collapsible collapsed">
  <legend><?php echo $row['Title']; ?></legend>
  <p><?php echo date("g:i ", strtotime($row['StartTime']))?>&mdash;<?php echo " " . date("g:i ", strtotime($row['EndTime']))?></p>
  <p><?php echo $row['Description']; ?></p>
  <p><?php echo $locationInfo; ?></p>
  <p><?php echo $row['Cost'];?></p>
  <p><?php echo $contactInfo; ?></p>
  </fieldset>
<?php  
}
?>
```

I've tried to throw everything in an iframe on the display page, it works but it throws off the jquery. So basically I the html that is output by the php to be displayed like it is on the widget page. I've tried to do something like  where widget.js includes:

```
document.write('<php include(path/to/widget.php); ?>');
```

Does anybody know the right way of doing this??

Comment: I guess you could do it with AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference the URL of the remote page, not the path to the remote page's PHP script:

```
$("#whatever").load("http://remote-server.com/your_script.php");
```